# add number as prefix

Tags: regex, notepad++, dreamweaver

I have list of number:

```
 19
 20 
 21
 22
 23
 24
 25
 26
 many more numbers...
```

I want to add one number to all of then as prefix so thay will all becam etree digit numbers:

```
 219
 220 
 221
 222
 223
 224
 225
 226
```

It should go lik this in find section: \S{2,}  than what should I put in replace section? 2$1 or what I em not expert.

Comment: Search for `^(\d{2})$` and replace by `2$1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all two digits and capture them (with parentheses).

`\b(\d\d)\b`

Replace captured groups with an additional 2 in front.

`2$1`